# Get information about attrubute type in user defined object type

Tags: oracle, attributes, oracle10g, user-defined-types, oracle-type

In oracle 11, i use column CHAR_USED in `DBA_TYPE_ATTRS`/`ALL_TYPE_ATTRS`/`USER_TYPE_ATTRS`.

```
select CHAR_USED from SYS.DBA_TYPE_ATTRS
```

But in 10 this column [does not exist](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2108.htm).

Test types:

```
create type TEST_TYPE_WITH_CHAR as object (
    A varchar2(10 char)
);

create type TEST_TYPE_WITH_BYTE as object (
    A varchar2(10 byte)
);
```

How to determine what type contains char, and which byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this info in 10g is there, but not exposed to us at all. so you have only a few options. (in 11g its only in the ALL view, not DBA/USER one unless they've added that in a recent patch)

1. dba_source will have it , but thats a manual parsing of the sql to get that out.
2. you can create a new view that joins to sys.attribute$ and extract `decode(bitand(properties, 4096), 4096, 'C', 'B')`
3. you can amend the existing *type_attr views (though this wouldn't be supported by Oracle). just add `decode(bitand(a.properties, 4096), 4096, 'C', 'B')` in the view select parts (where "a" is the reference to sys.attribute$).

an example of the new view..

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production

SQL> create view type_chars
  2  as
  3  select ta.owner, ta.type_name, ta.attr_name, decode(bitand(a.properties, 4096), 4096, 'C', 'B') char_used
  4    from sys.attribute$ a, sys.type$ t, sys.obj$ o, dba_objects ob, dba_type_attrs ta
  5  where ta.owner = ob.owner
  6    and ta.type_name = ob.object_name
  7    and a.toid = t.toid
  8    and a.version# = t.version#
  9    and t.toid = o.oid$
 10    and o.subname is null
 11    and ob.object_id = o.obj#
 12    and a.name = ta.attr_name;

View created.

SQL> create type mytype as object (a varchar2(20), b number, c varchar2(30 char));
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> select * from type_chars where type_name = 'MYTYPE' and owner= user;

OWNER                          TYPE_NAME                      ATTR_NAME                      C
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ -
DTD_TRADE                      MYTYPE                         A                              B
DTD_TRADE                      MYTYPE                         B                              B
DTD_TRADE                      MYTYPE                         C                              C

SQL>
```